# Can heap be used for strict priority queuing given priority isn't guaranteed between nodes of different branch levels

Tags: heap, priority-queue

I wonder about heap and priority queuing.

Seems with heap structure that we don't control whether left or right child has highest or lowest value of the two. Similarly between tree levels nodes at a level further from root can have higher priorities than nodes closer to the root of another branch.

Are we supposed not to care?
What if we require strict priority is heap still the way to go?
If so how would we implement them (sorted trees)?

Comment: Why do you think it should matter? As long as the heap always returns the current highest priority item when you ask for it, what does it matter where things are in relation to each other? The only time it might matter is if you want equal items to be removed in FIFO order, and that's easily accomplished by adding another comparison field. I could provide a real answer if you can give an example of what you're concerned about.

Comment: Tanks Jim for your input. Went back to some YouTube lectures and I think I had misunderstood how to add elements to the heap (queue). Before I had only coded heapify and heap sort, now I coded on my own delete/dequeue and add/enqueue. Add(to maxheap): add item at end of array, find its parent and compare, if new item has higher value swap places and call recursively same function with array and new position(parent-pos)as input. Stop when done which happens if the comparison fails or at start of array. This is the bubble-up procedure. I understand also now how equal values can be handled.Thanks